# Css - dynamic font size

Tags: css

We are developing a website for a school project: this website must also be available on mobile devices (and tablets).
We have attained this goal, except for an issue with the **font-size**: we've set this property manually via `@media query`.

Does there exist a way by make the font-size can be made dynamic without the use of percent?

Thanks

Comment: There are always ems :)

Comment: I suppose he speaks about viewport rendering

Comment: I think it would be better to use @media because it is better for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should consider this option:

```
.yourClass {
    font-size: 2.0vw;
}
```

It meaning 2.0% of **viewport** width. You can also use 2.0vh (2.0% viewport height)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how others would feel about this solution (since some will view it as unnecessary scripting), but it works really well for me.  I use jQuery to set font sizes as a percentage of the screen size.

```
var FONT_SCALE = 0.027;

function initFontSizes() {
    $(".text-element").css("font-size", $(window).height() * FONT_SCALE);
}
```

If you wanted you could add it as a jQuery function so you can call it on any object:

```
jQuery.fn.setFontSize(scale) {
    $(this).css("font-size", $(window).height() * scale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to muddy the waters with a bit of javascript, you could go for something along the lines of:

```
$(function(){
    resizeFont();    
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizeFont();    
    });
    function resizeFont(){
        var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
            psize = windowWidth/ 10;
        $("p").css("font-size",psize);
    }
});
```

You'd need to a bit of maths to sort it out properly though.

http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/5Hnxa/